# Devise Cancan registration for Users and Companies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

In Rails 3 application I have 2 logical entities - User and Company.
I'd like to have 2 different forms for sign up(for users and for companies). Also, will be great to have one login form for both of them.

What I have now - configured Devise+Cancan for User model with two roles(user, company), so I have now "/users/sign_in" and "/users/sign_up".

I'd like to have following urls in my application:

```
/login
/users/signup
/companies/signup
```

One other question is how to organize relationship between User and Company, should the company inherited from User or I shoud use aggregation - User has_one Company ? I prefer second variant and plan to user user.company with cancan user role = "company".

Please help me with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple models in devise. You can add a company as well.

`rails generate devise company`

This will get you the url you mentioned.

Regarding the relationship between User and Company It's common to use:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

You have to add a `company_id` column to the User model in a migration to make this happen. There is no inheritance then. Users and companies are treated completely separate. But you are able to access `user.company` and `company.users`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is it possible to implement mentioned behaviour with one single model ? Maybe define different Devise registration controllers for different urls ?

Comment: Not sure if this is working but
`class Company < User;
end` would use single table inheritance. You are holding all data in the users table but have to add a **type** column to make single table inheritance working.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html as well.

Comment: I have tried the similar solution and got a mess of models and  helpers methods on my pages. Now, I prefer to have one single model that will aggregate different objects and use it based on the model's Cancan Role and abilities. But how to be with mentioned urls in my top question ? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to create with devise_scope  ?